# como remuevo un repositorio nuevo creado en git

Tags: git

hola buenas tardes estoy aprendiendo a usar git, pero cree un repositorio en donde no debia hacerlo, para eliminarlo como lo hago? puse clear, pero al parecer eso solo elimina el codigo  anterior escrito , no el repositorio como tal, muchas gracias por su tiempo al leerme.

asi dice mi codigo :

danie@DESKTOP-VPDHL6H MINGW64 ~ (master)
$ pwd
/c/Users/danie

danie@DESKTOP-VPDHL6H MINGW64 ~ (master)

Comment: borra la carpeta .git y listo